# How to only add specific value to a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I make sure it only concat one value once it already got value?
For example is the message already got the text "cat", how do I make the "dog" doesnt include?

```
SELECT name, message,

concat(

if(message like '%cat%', 'cat', ''),
if(message like '%dog%', 'dog', ''),
) as intent

FROM table;
```

Comment: Add sample and output data.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    name,
    message,
    CASE WHEN message LIKE '%cat%' THEN 'cat'
         WHEN message LIKE '%dog%' THEN 'dog' END AS intent
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cas use DISTINCT to pick a value just once as below-

```
SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT N) 
FROM 
(
    select 'Dog' N UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CAT' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'CAT'
)A
```